# Turn data in array and implode ids with commas

Tags: php, arrays

I got an element which shows some discount offers. Every page has related offers, so in my query I made it so that every offer that is related to the current page comes first, and the rest is added after.

Because there are multiple ids I need to seperate them from eachoter to use them in a query (with `ID IN('1', '2')`). How can I do this? When I have the following query:

```
foreach($offercr as $aanb){
  //Haal alles op van fe_elements waar het id gelijk is aan element_id van fe_connections
    $offer1                     = "SELECT *
                                    FROM  `web_fieldsandfilters_elements`
                                    WHERE  `id` = '".$aanb['element_id']."'";
    $offercon1                  = $conn->query($offer1);
    $offercr1                       = array();
    while ($offercr1[]          = $offercon1->fetch_array());
    foreach($offercr1 as $offerresult){
        $offerresultfinal .= $offerresult['item_id'];
    }
}
```

The result of `$offerresultfinal`  = 107108109, how can I get this to 107,108,109? I tried:

```
$usable  = implode(",", $offerresultfinal);
```

The output is not an array so it doesn't work like that.

Comment: `$item_ids = []; foreach ($offercr1 as $row) { $item_ids[] = $row['item_id']; } $useable = implode(',', $item_ids);`?

Comment: You are right. I missed the fetch_array() part. Deleted my post as it was incorrect. Thanks :)

Comment: @Cyclone Almost there, but this produces 2 commas instead of 1

Comment: @twan I'm not sure what you mean with 2 commas? Can you show the output?

Comment: @Cyclone The output I get is: `107,,108,,109,,` It also adds commas at the end, I thought implode prevented that from happening?

Comment: @twan - Yes it should. Probably this is because you have empty values in the array? You need to check the content of `$offercr1` to solve this.

Comment: @Cyclone Thanks, I checked if there was an id present and only continue the code if it is, that fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes to your code :-

```
foreach($offercr as $aanb){
  //Haal alles op van fe_elements waar het id gelijk is aan element_id van fe_connections
    $offer1                     = "SELECT *
                                    FROM  `web_fieldsandfilters_elements`
                                    WHERE  `id` = '".$aanb['element_id']."'";
    $offercon1                  = $conn->query($offer1);
    $offercr1                       = array();
    while ($offercr1[]          = $offercon1->fetch_array());
    $offerresultfinal=[];
    $i=0;
    foreach($offercr1 as $offerresult){
        $offerresultfinal[$i]= $offerresult['item_id'];
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    $useable = implode(',', $offerresultfinal);

}
```

Implode will join all the array elements with the comma symbol